# How to get request attributes in authentication-success-handler

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to do few things in authentication-success-handler and I need to access few values which was part of initial request data being posted to Spring security.
I am posting following information when user trying to do login

1. j_username
2. j_password
3. storeCode

Spring security is able to authenticate user successfully and is calling "`authentication-success-handler`".

```
public class WebshopAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler
{

    public WebshopAuthenticationSuccessHandler() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(final HttpServletRequest request,
            final HttpServletResponse response, final Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
        request.getAttribute( "storeCode" );
        attr.getRequest().getAttribute( "storeCode" );
     }
}
```

But in all way, I am not able to get value of `storeCode` and its coming as `null`.
Not sure what I am doing wrong.
I am assuming that Spring is creating a new instance of Request and response while calling  `onAuthenticationSuccess`, but how can I pass/ retrieve values which passed passed from the login page?

Comment: Does the `WebshopAuthenticationSuccessHandler` come into play during the POST or in a following GET?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: not sure what you are asking? from my login page, I am doing a POST

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the data is from an HTTP POST request, you should be using `getParameter`, not `getAttribute`. Attributes are server-side state only, not submitted by the client.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, and from last few minutes I was pointing Spring security about this issue without even looking even once on my code :(.